# Wordpress Home Page Points to Domain, but no Other Pages

Tags: wordpress, url

I have just created a new website in Wordpress, and I pointed the site to my domain: [www.hmsp.ca](http://www.hmsp.ca). What I noticed is the homepage of the site is www.hmsp.ca, but when I navigate to other pages within the site, it shows an address that is related to my hosting provider. Example being the 'Teams' page on my site. The url for the teams page is: http://03c82ab.netsolhost.com/hsp/teams/ Does anyone know why this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.hmsp.ca/wp-admin/options-general.php for the site-URL and the home-URL. Are they both `https://www.hmsp.ca`?

If not, change them to https://www.hmsp.ca.

If yes, I think you have to look into your DB and find/replace `http://03c82ab.netsolhost.com/hsp/` width `https://www.hmsp.ca`.

Comment: I tried this the other day, and my site broke. The style sheets couldn't be found and I couldn't log into wordpress. I needed to go back into my FTP server and fix it after that.

Comment: So where did wp tried to find the style sheet? And why did the login failed? And what did you change (options or DB)?